# POSTing Data with the WebClient in C# on Windows Phone is not working for me

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1

```
// string url = "http://localhost:19315/test/postWithParamters?param1=1&param2=2";
string url = "http://m.mydomain.com/1.0/services/logException?p1=WindowsPhone&p2=a&p3=b&p4=2012-05-01T14:57:32.8375298-04:00&p5=someuser&p6=test&p7=info&p8=data";

WebClient postWithParamsClient = new WebClient();
postWithParamsClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(postWithParamsClient_UploadStringCompleted);

Uri address = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
postWithParamsClient.Headers["Content-Length"] = url.Length.ToString();
postWithParamsClient.UploadStringAsync(address, "POST", string.Empty);

private void postWithParamsClient_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Error == null)
    MessageBox.Show("WebClient: " + e.Result);
  else
    MessageBox.Show("WebClient: " + e.Error.Message);
}
```

When I execute the above code, it works with the first URL that is commented out. However, when I execute the second code, I get the generic "NotFound" error. Nothing is posted in Fiddler. So I took the url in question and pasted it into the "Composer". When I execute the request, it works as expected.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I make the call to that specific endpoint? It works in Fiddler. It works from JQuery. I just can't get it to work from SL for WP.

Thank you for any insights.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to encode the arguments.

```
string url = string.Format("http://m.mydomain.com/1.0/services/logException?p1=WindowsPhone&p2=a&p3=b&p4={0}&p5=someuser&p6=test&p7=info&p8=data", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("2012-05-01T14:57:32.8375298-04:00"));
```

Also, in general: you are not doing a POST request here, but a GET request. The Content-Length shouldn't be set to the length of the URL, but to the length of your POST data (which is string.Empty in this case).

Actually, you could just call DownloadStringAsync(url) to achieve the same, since you're not posting anything anyway.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
```

To achieve a POST request, you could try this:

```
string url = "http://m.mydomain.com/1.0/services/logException";
string postdata = string.Format("p1=WindowsPhone&p2=a&p3=b&p4={0}&p5=someuser&p6=test&p7=info&p8=data", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("2012-05-01T14:57:32.8375298-04:00"));

WebClient postWithParamsClient = new WebClient();
postWithParamsClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(postWithParamsClient_UploadStringCompleted);

postWithParamsClient.Headers["Content-Length"] = postdata.Length.ToString();
postWithParamsClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(url), "POST", postdata);

private void postWithParamsClient_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Error == null)
    MessageBox.Show("WebClient: " + e.Result);
  else
    MessageBox.Show("WebClient: " + e.Error.Message);
}
```

Also, the MessageBox will probably throw an InvalidOperationException (Cross Thread). If it does, invoke them like this:

```
private void postWithParamsClient_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
    if (e.Error == null)
      MessageBox.Show("WebClient: " + e.Result);
    else
      MessageBox.Show("WebClient: " + e.Error.Message);
  });
}
```

Comment: Suppose you have written your above to above code in a void function. and that function you are calling to somewhere else than Please let me know how you will ensures that your function named 'postWithParamsClient_UploadStringCompleted' will execute and return the response from server. I hope you are getting my point. once again i explain in brief. Suppose you want to save the server response after send the successful POST reqeust. As i have mentioned the event name when will execute and we can save the response in my global variable ? I am facing this problem while using your approach.